# Optimize regular expression for path replacement

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have following string `var foo = require('foo/bar');` which I want to change to `var foo = require('../../foo/bar');`.

So far I wrote following code which would do this:

```
var search  = 'foo/bar';
var replace = '../../foo/bar';

var regex = new RegExp('require[(](\"|\')' + search + '(\"|\')[)]', 'g');
var source = 'var foo = require(\'foo/bar\')';

source.replace(regex, 'require(\'' + replace + '\')');
```

However as you see this is very inefficient. What could I do to make this regex a bit shorter. For example:

- only have to replace the path and not to rewrite require with `require(\'' + replace + '\')'`
- make `(\"|\')` and `[(]` shorter
- anything else?

Best,
Bo

**Edit:**
I am doing this replacement on complete javascript source files.

**Edit2:**
What is necessary to change `var foobar = require('foo/bar');` to `var foobar = require('../../foo/baz/bar')` when `foo/` and `../../foo/baz/` should be variable?

Comment: inefficient, how? by milli/tenths/seconds? unless you `require` megabytes of useless code it'll be no different than any other major website user experience. Personally I'd concern myself with the user interaction experience rather than `require` portions as you'll never escape the 3rd party crap that is google/facebook/foo/da/blah that I assume you would include. Google! a fantastic example of delaying/hanging your site for no apparent reason is something we seem to put up with. A more efficient `require` is useless when 3rd party nonsense controls 99% of your traffic imo :)

Comment: @gwillie readability at least if you can argue with that on regex :) However there is still a use case missing (forgot to mention)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
var search  = 'foo/bar';
var source = "var foo = require('foo/bar')";
var regex = new RegExp('(require)\\((["\'])(' + search + ')\\2\\)', 'g');

var repl = source.replace(regex, "$1('../../$3')");
//=> var foo = require('../../foo/bar')
```

Comment: What would I have to do if I also want to allow to replace "foo/" with "../../foo/baz/" in the require call?

Comment: In that you will need to use: `source.replace(regex, "$1('../../$3/baz/')");`

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to replace the entire foo in a specified scope (e.g. `require('')` ?)

Comment: Yes definitely it can be done, just don't use `$3` in the replacement part.

Comment: Then I am missing the filename "bar" (Updated the start post for a more complete example)

Comment: If search term is just `foo` in your `EDIT2` then regex will also need to change. Something like: `var regex = new RegExp('(require)\\((["\'])(' + search + ')([^"\']*)\\2\\)', 'g');` and then use: `source.replace(regex, "$1('../../$3/baz$4')");`

Comment: Also may I request that you please open a new question for further EDIT and changing requirements. Usually SO admins don't like new Questions and answer sessions in comments section.

Comment: I think I may found a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21497574/dynamic-replace-in-regular-expression-scope (Trick is to skip the closing delimiter). Hope this is save though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative :

```
var str = "var foo = require('foo/bar');";
str = str.split(/(')/);
str.splice(2, 0, '../../');
str = str.join('');
```

Even simpler :

```
"var foo = require('foo/bar');".replace(/'([^']+)'/, "'../../$1'")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you could do the replacement before wrapping your path inside the `var xxx = require()` statement.

Optimizing code that starts by undoing what has been done just before seems a bit inefficient.

Besides, it seems you already know the target path (`foo/bar` in your example), but it is not even necessary to use that.

The regexp here boils down to splitting the string after the opening quote and inserting the `../../` prefix.

You could do that with

```
source = source.split(/["']/,2).join('"../../')+'");';
```

The regexp is a constant, so you could put it into a variable to have it compiled once and for all.
That would probably be more efficient than generating and recompiling the regexp from your example each time.

But anyway, I wonder how many such strings you would have to replace to start noticing a performance hit.