# Dynamic replace in regular expression scope

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to rewrite some require paths in JavaScript source files:

Example (`foo` => `../../../foo/baz`):

1. `var a = require('foo/a');` => `var b = require('../../../foo/baz/a');`
2. `var a = require('foo/../b');` => `var b = require('../../../foo/baz/../b');`

**Note:** This replacement will be done on a complete js source files. So `require('` and `')` **must** be used as delimiter!

So far we have figured out to use some setup like this:

```
var source = '';

source += "var a = require('foo/a');\n";
source += "var b = require('foo/../b');\n";
source += "console.log(a + b);";

var options = {
  'foo': '../../../foo/baz'
};

for (var key in options) {
  var regex = new RegExp('require[(](\"|\')' + key, 'g');

  source = source.replace(regex, "require('" + options[key]);
}

console.log(source);
```

Though above source code is working. I am not sure if this is save as I am just skipping the closing delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does it:

```
str = str.replace(/require\((['"])([^'"]*)foo\/([^'"]*)(['"])/g, "require($1$2../../../foo/baz/$3$4");
```

Here's that regex live: http://regex101.com/r/bE5jI4

Explanation:

- `require` matches the characters `require` literally (case sensitive)
- `\(` matches the character `(` literally
- 1st Capturing group `(['"])`

  - `['"]` match either `'` or `"` literally
- 2nd Capturing group `([^'"]*)`

  - `[^'"]*` match a single character not present in the list below

    - Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
  - `'"` a single character in the list `'"` literally
- `foo` matches the characters `foo` literally (case sensitive)
- `\/` matches the character `/` literally
- 3rd Capturing group `([^'"]*)`

  - `[^'"]*` match a single character not present in the list below

    - Quantifier: Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
    - `'"` a single character in the list `'"` literally
- 4th Capturing group `(['"])`

  - `['"]` match `'` or `"` literally

You may have to tweak it if there's optional whitespace before the opening quotes, or if your paths may contain `'` or `"` characters. (In that latter case, you'll need two replacements, one when the wrapper quotes are `'` and the other when they're `"`.)

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var source = '';
source += "var a = require('foo/a');\n";
source += "var b = require('foo/../b');\n";
source += "console.log(a + b);";

var options = {
  'foo': '../../../foo/baz'
};

for (var key in options) {
  var regex = new RegExp('(require)\\((["\'])(' + key + ')([^"\']*)\\2\\)', 'g');
  source = source.replace(regex, "$1('" + options[key] + "$4')");
}
console.log(source);
```

### OUTPUT:

```
var a = require('../../../foo/baz/a');
var b = require('../../../foo/baz/../b');
console.log(a + b);
```